# Can not store generated class by POCO Entity Generator in Session state

Tags: entity-framework-4, session-state

I have an EDMX model in my project. I use POCO entity generator to generate my entity classes and add an Serializable attribute to all my POCO entities. but steel I got this error :

```
Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
```

About a week ago I got this error and my problem solved  by adding that attribute. But today i got this error again !!!
What did I wrong ?!!Is there any thing that i should add to my POCO generator to resolve this ?!!

**UPDATE 1** :

Here the code I used in my web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="30" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" />
```

**UPDATE 2** :

Here my POCO generator :

```
// Emit Entity Types
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
    bool entityHasNullableFKs = entity.NavigationProperties.Any(np => np.GetDependentProperties().Any(p=>ef.IsNullable(p)));
#>
[Serializable()]
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<#
....
```